# Partial extension of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, newline, extend, overwrite

## Context

I am learning R and therefore use the imports85.RData (dim 205 x 27)

My goal is to add a line with only partial col.contents within a script to the data.frame.

The column 'make' is a factor with 22 levels.

## Example

What I did:

I copied 1st line and appended it to the d.f . Then I overwrote 1st line with NAs. So far, so good.

## Question

Now my problem: I tried several methods to overwrite, nothing works!

```
cars$make[1] <- "foo"
cars[1,3] <- "foo"
cars[1,3] <- factor("foo")
cars[1,3] <- as.factor("foo")
...
```

and a lot more of this kind!

Answer (score 0):

... what I found till now:

If overwriting with a level, not included in the factor, I have do extend the factor first, e.g.

`levels(cars$make <-c(levels(cars$make),'new.foo')`

Afterwards a cell can be overwritten with e.g.

`cars$make[3] <- 'new.foo'`

BUT if the cell content is NA, this don't work!
Thx 4 help!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! (there is a misstyping in the example d.f 'alfa-romero')

Building a new observation with all NAs in its variables ...

```
cars <- rbind(cars,cars[1,]); cars[1,] <- NA
```

... expanding the levels and overwriting ...

```
levels(cars$make) <- c(levels(cars$make),'wolga'); cars$make[1] <- 'wolga'
```

... brings the desired ...
[result ;-)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTeXs.png)